# Devart Entity Developer Can't See Certain Picklist Fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, devart

I'm having a problem seeing certain picklist fields from a Standard Salesforce table called Lead in my Devart Entity Developer Model.

I am unable to see the below item in the Model I generate using Devart.

- Lead.Status_Reason is a Picklist and IS NOT a Global Value Set. It IS
  a Required Field

I am able to see the below item in the Model I generate using Devart.

- Lead.Status is a Picklist and IS a Global Value Set. It IS a Required Field
- Account.Sub_Source is a Picklist and IS a Global Value Set. It IS NOT a Required Field
- Account.ApprovedStates is a Multi-Select Picklist and IS a Global
  Value Set but IS NOT Required
- User.DigestFrequency Appears to be a System Generated Picklist so I
  would assume that it is a Global Value Set and it IS Required

The common denominator appears to be that Lead.Status_Reason is not a Global Value Set. Can anyone confirm that hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! There's Cache setting in the Devart Entity Developer tool connection settings under the advanced section. [see image]. When I tried to update the Lead table in the model it would tell me that there was a change but it would never update the model with the new fields. I change the Refresh Metadata to true and set System Objects to True then it forced a refresh and behold the field appeared.

[image].

[image]